# Characteristic function and point masses

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be some random variable with characteristic function $\hat{X}$. Show that $X$ has no point masses if and only if
>
> $$
> \lim_{T\to +\infty}\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T\left\lvert \hat{X}(t)\right\rvert^2\mathrm dt=0.
> $$

I think I have to consider the probability $P(X − Y = 0)$ where $Y$ is independent of $X$ and $X=Y$ in distribution, but I don't know how proceed.

Comment: What is your definition of a point mass?

Comment: A probability mass function is a function that gives the probability that a discrete random variable is exactly equal to some value. So I think that the point masses that I have to consider in the exercise are those that have the probability exactly equal to some value.

Comment: Did you try to work with the inversion formula for characteristic functions?